# Can I use a trademarked name as part of mobile app title?

Tags: trademark

I have created an app which is basicly a tool for some other trademarked product.
Because I want users looking for an app like this to know what is it for, I would like to use the trademarked name of the product as part of the app title, for example: "Product name tool". Also I would like to use the trademarked name in the description of the app a few times (Keyword search optimization) but I would put something like "App is not affiliated with Product name" in short description and in both top and bottom of long description.

Could this cause a trademark infringement or some other problems?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this directly against what trademarks are supposed to protect: The customer will think that your product is connected to someone else's product.

So this is in my opinion trademark infringement, and it sure could cause the problem that you are sued for trademark infringement (which is a different problem, since you can be sued no matter whether you are infringing or not, and being sued is a problem on its own).

The company owning the trademark may even be forced to stop you from using their trademark, since not doing so weakens the trademark and can lead to loss of the trademark.